# What is an example of constructive vs. nonconstructive type theory?

Tags: terminology, type-theory, constructive-mathematics

I am trying to get some basic terminology down related to type theory, and am currently on understanding the difference between "constructive type theories" and "nonconstructive type theories", as mentioned [here](http://imps.mcmaster.ca/doc/seven-virtues.pdf):

> Like first-order logic, Church’s type theory is classical in the sense that
> it admits **nonconstructive** reasoning principles such as the law of excluded
> middle and double negation elimination. P. Martin-Löf introduced in 1972 a
> **constructive form of type theory** now known as Martin-Löf type theory [42].
> Most constructive type theories, including Martin-Löf type theory, embody
> the Curry-Howard isomorphism [33] that elegantly connects proving theorems in type theory to writing programs in lambda calculus. Constructive
> type theories also have a close connection to category theory and have been
> extensively used to formalize constructive mathematics and ideas from theoretical computer science [12, 39].

[Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof) of constructive vs. nonconstructive proofs doesn't help elucidate the concepts. I am not entirely sure this has to do with [Constructivism in Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)), but it seems like it.

What is meant exactly by **constructive** vs. **nonconstructive** in terms of type theory? What is an example to demonstrate the difference between constructive and nonconstructive type theories? How would I explain the difference between constructive and nonconstructive type theories to a non-mathematician, such as a software engineer?

Comment: In your quote: "nonconstructive reasoning principles such as the law of excluded middle and double negation elimination". I suggest you look up these principles first.

Comment: How you would explain those things to a software engineer may depend very much on how they encounter/interact with type theory. I don't know enough to answer this sort of question. But given the relationship between constructive mathematics and programs (e.g. the work of Martin-Löf), I imagine that for many software engineers, the answer is "nonconstructive type theory is something you won't encounter/have to worry about at all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is mentionned in the quoted text, the different between constructive and nonconstructive type theory has to do with constructivism in Mathematics.
As there are many variations of [constructive mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constructive+mathematics), it is just impossible to give an accurate meaning of the difference between constructive, and nonconstructive.

But there is also technical meaning to constructivity in type theory.
A type theory is constructive if it enjoys the [canonicity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112893/what-does-canonicity-property-mean-in-type-theory) property: every term of a given type computes to a [canonical form](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+form), that is a combination of the sole constructors of that type.

Using nonconstructive axioms such as excluded middle, you can prove the existence of a term of a given type, but you are not able to compute that term (in a canonical form).